# What is the font of Bernard Tschumi's Exhibition in Shanghai Power Station of Art?

Tags: typography, font-identification

I went to Bernard Tschumi's exhibition (Bernard Tschumi: Concept and Notation) in Shanghai Power Station of Art, I'd like to know what the font of "Bernard Tschumi" in this poster.

[image]

I used Whatthefont multiple times to identify the font, the best guess is Red Ring Bold:

[image]

although they do look similar, but the dot above "i" shows the obvious difference, and when looking closely, the "a", "d", etc., all of them seem different.

Answer (score 4):

Likely [Gotham Bold:](http://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/styles/)

[image]

The square dot on the 'i', tall x-height and the way the strokes of the 'c' are cut are strong indicators.

Comment: Looks pretty spot on to me. Width of the 'B' is another good indicator.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Looks like it's the one.

Comment: @xawyzen You're very welcome. If this answer helped you, don't forget to accept it by clicking on the checkmark so that others may find it.

Comment: @Dre I'm new here in StackExchange, the vote will not be displayed until I earn 15 reputations...